# How can i verify google play in-app purchase in php?

Tags: php, android, google-play

I wish to verify a receipt of in-app purchase in an app through google play using a php page.
How should i do it?

Comment: please see my sample code in this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35718040/2710505

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm no PHP expert so I'm not going to post any code, but the overall process is *very* straight forward and it should be dead easy to port to PHP. You need three things to verify a purchase:

1. Your app's public key (from Services & APIs in Google Play Developer
   console)
2. The original JSON of the purchase
3. The purchase signature

If you implement in-app billing on Android using the [IabHelper classes](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html) you'll get a [Purchase](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/Purchase.java) object when you make a successful purchase or when you query the inventory. The Purchase object contains two methods that you need: [Purchase.getOriginalJson()](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/Purchase.java#58) and [Purchase.getSignature()](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/Purchase.java#59).

Securely store your app's public key on your server and POST the signature and the original JSON (base64 encode it before you send it) to you server. Retrieve the signature and json from $_POST and refer to Google's [Java implementation of how to verify a purchase](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/Security.java). [It seems as though you can use PHPs built in openssl_verify function](https://gist.github.com/menny/1985010#file-verify_market_in_app-php).

Comment: What should I pass to [ https://gist.github.com/menny/1985010#file-verify_market_in_app-php ] this page's signed_data parameter? I am using unity and c#, at there, pass purchase.OriginalJson is signed_data?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the signed data should be the entire receipt (ie point #2 in my list above)

Comment: Correct me if I'm doing, but doesn't the newer docs show a method of verification (server side only) that doesn't use all this base64 and signed stuff? Just using the purchase token and queuing against the get()