# In-app billing for hybrid app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-play-services, hybrid

I'm projecting a hybrid app using cordova. My app will offer a monthly subscription to change the user plan(default or premium account).

So, as I'm making a hybrid app, I'm programming in web language(HTML, JS, PHP,...).

But, according the Google's policy center, I have to use the Google Play in-app billing as the method of payment.

How can I integrate the Google play in-app billing system if it only has support for JAVA(I would have to use Android Studio, but I won't use it, because I'm making a hybrid app using the Intel xdk)?

Comment: Possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/17143807/4387543

Comment: It isn't the same thing, I want to know how to implement. This topic is talking about how to verify.

Comment: You will need to find a Cordova plugin that supports Google in-app purchase.  You will also need to find one that supports Apple in-app purchase if you want to provide your app on the Apple App Store.